# SubProtocolWebSocketHandler - No handlers

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs, spring-web

I have this ugly error during deploying Spring app on JBoss.

```
18:11:16,025 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/consumer]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:770) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65) [spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.start(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:234) [spring-websocket-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 17 more
```

This error occurred during init SubProtocolWebSocketHandler. I also paste below my MessageBroker implementation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Component("messageBroker")
public class MessageBroker implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/random").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry messageBrokerRegistry) {
        messageBrokerRegistry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app").enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration webSocketTransportRegistration) {
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> handlerMethodArgumentResolvers) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> handlerMethodReturnValueHandlers) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        return true;
    }
}
```

I must to add that I am using Spring 4.1.3.RELEASE and Spring Messaging 4.1.3.RELEASE. Thanks for help!

Comment: could you give more info on your app container? Is this Wildfly? Which version?

Comment: Weid...I change version of Spring to 4.0.1.RELEASE and Spring Messaging  to 4.0.5.RELEASE and it seems that "No handlers" did not appear any more.